# View and Search PDF or doc Files in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, pdf, react-native

Can anyone please provide any library for displaying and searching in a PDF or doc files in React Native? .

I've tested WebView , [react-native-pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/react-native-pdf-lib) ,[react-native-pdf-view](https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-pdf-view) , [react-native-doc-viewer](https://github.com/philipphecht/react-native-doc-viewer) library

but i can't search in any files

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one library : https://pspdfkit.com/pdf-sdk/react-native/

This is not free but allows you to search. There is free trial available.